# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'replaceWorkspacePath'

Tags: arcpy, unicode, attributeerror

I must of written this code using 15 different structures with no luck. I am simply trying to take an old layer 'Windfarms' stored in 'C:\Users\darle\Desktop\MXD_Test\Test.gdb' and replace it with 'New_Wind_Farm' stored in 'C:\Users\darle\Desktop\New_Shapes\new.gdb'.

my code is as followed:

```
import arcpy, os
for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
fullpath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
    if extension.lower() == ".mxd":
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
        layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,'WindFarms')
        for lyr in layers:
            layer_source = lyr.dataSource                  
            layer_source.replaceWorkspacePath(#New shape path, ....
            "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE","New_Wind_Farm")
            mxd.save()
         del mxd
```

The error I get is in the title. The documentation states that replaceWorkspacePath is for changing both file path and name. What am I missing?

Comment: which line has the error?

Comment: layer_source is a string not an object

Comment: Error is on line: layer_source.replaceWorkspacePath. I have also tried: lyr.dataSource.replaceWorkspacePath()